# asp.net core Jwt Tokenl SSL issues

Tags: docker, nginx, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, docker-swarm

We are running a few aspnet core APIs in a docker swarm with nginx as the reverse proxy server.

We have been running this set up for a while without any issue. However recently we added an SSL certificate that we got from letsencrypt. Since then we notice that after we hit the /api/TokenAuth/Authenticate endpoint and get assign a Bearer token if we try and make a subsequent call using the token that was just assigned, the call sometimes fail and we get a 302 (it works about 40% of the time). It seems that if we try using that same token again after some time has passed than the call works.

It's strange that this only seems to be an issue if we have ssl(https) on.

I cannot replicate the issue locally. It seems to only show up when the api is deployed to our docker swarm (which is running nginx and the api as containers, nginx handles the ssl cert).

Does anyone have any idea what the issue might be? Has anyone experienced something like this before that could point me in the right direction?

There are two console below: The top one is an example of it working and I got the expected results back. The bottom is the response when it fails. 
[image]

Comment: Looks like "something with caching". So the first thing I'd check is if the request reaches your app. (does your server or nginx respond with 302?). Then it looks as if you do not send any "no cache" headers?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. We have 3 instances/replica of api that is set to issue the Token. The server time on each server seems to be off by seconds. Therefore if the server that issues the token is ahead of the server that processes the subsequent request, then the token is not valid yet.